What is the voltmeter measuring the PD of?
In the circuit diagram, the cell has an internal resistance, but when the switch is closed what does the voltmeter measure,
the pd of the cell, or the components in series?


It actually measures its own voltage drop. The volt meter allows a very small current to flow across itself in order to sample the voltage, in parallel with the other components.
At steady state the voltage across the meter and across the series of components, and across the battery (absolute value) will be the same, assuming equal or negligible line resistance.

Steady state isn't required for the equality you described. It's also equal in an AC circuit, or at any instant in a transient, as long as the lumped circuit conditions are valid.

Can't you swap the voltmeter and the cell, and theoretically the voltmeter would have infinite resistance, so the cell would be in series with the resistors?

Yes you could. But the meter would still be measuring the same thing.
